# Can't modify instagram font awesome tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```html
<li>
  <a title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="instagram" href="https://instagram.com/" data-original-title="Instagram">
    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

It generates the following icon:

[image]

But I want to create a similar icon instead:

[image]

I have tried modifying the part below but it won't work.

`<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>`

Any suggestion on how to continue?

Comment: Can you show us your `CSS` style?

Comment: Give your <li> some padding and then give it a border-radius of 100%. Then give it that blue colored background.

Comment: You need to add your styles on this class : `.fa-instagram:before`

Comment: I have no CSS for the instagram icon. Is there a way to copy the properties from the facebook icon (see the left icon in image no.1). Because it has a blue background like I want it

Comment: @RobinLundgren You can use image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you have in `font-awesome` at a better view also, it shows this way:

[image]

This is not available until you use an image or SVG for this. If the issue is about the background colour, please give:

```
.instagram {
  backgroud: #99f;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Using **SVG**:

```css
a {background: #99f; padding: 5px; width: 32px; height: 32px; border-radius: 100%; margin: 15px;}
a, img, svg {display: block; width: 32px; height: 32px;}
a svg path, a svg d {color: #fff; background: #fff; fill: #fff;}
```

```html
<a class="instagram">
  <img src="https://othermachine.co/images/instagram-icon.svg" />
</a>


<a class="instagram">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

       width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">

    <path id="instagram-icon" d="M341.205,197.143H460.93v183.795c0,44.77-36.292,81.062-81.062,81.062H132.133

                                 c-44.769,0-81.062-36.293-81.062-81.062V197.143H170.26c-12.2,17.141-19.399,38.087-19.399,60.729

                                 c0,57.919,46.953,104.872,104.873,104.872c57.919,0,104.872-46.953,104.872-104.872

                                 C360.605,235.229,353.405,214.283,341.205,197.143z M460.93,131.062v53.239H330.447c-19.022-19.315-45.465-31.302-74.714-31.302

                                 c-29.251,0-55.693,11.986-74.714,31.302H51.07v-53.239c0-27.322,13.532-51.469,34.245-66.154v87.289h16.62v-96.36

                                 c3.77-1.516,7.679-2.752,11.704-3.691v100.052h16.621V50.047c0.625-0.015,1.245-0.047,1.873-0.047h9.598v102.196h16.62V50h221.517

                                 C424.638,50,460.93,86.292,460.93,131.062z M423.879,96.897c0-7.181-5.822-13.002-13.003-13.002h-43.821

                                 c-7.183,0-13.003,5.821-13.003,13.002v44.785c0,7.181,5.82,13.002,13.003,13.002h43.821c7.181,0,13.003-5.821,13.003-13.002V96.897z

                                 M174.938,257.872c0-24.188,10.698-45.909,27.593-60.729c5.926-5.197,12.613-9.539,19.875-12.842

                                 c10.169-4.625,21.447-7.224,33.327-7.224c11.881,0,23.157,2.599,33.326,7.224c7.263,3.303,13.95,7.645,19.876,12.842

                                 c16.895,14.82,27.592,36.542,27.592,60.729c0,44.55-36.243,80.794-80.794,80.794C211.183,338.666,174.938,302.422,174.938,257.872z

                                 M196.286,257.872c0,32.979,26.735,59.712,59.714,59.712c32.979,0,59.713-26.733,59.713-59.712c0-32.98-26.733-59.713-59.713-59.713

                                 C223.021,198.159,196.286,224.892,196.286,257.872z"/>

  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: @RobinLundgren Oh yes, that's possible.

Comment: Searching for `instagram svg` I got this: https://othermachine.co/images/instagram-icon.svg. You can use this.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be kind enough to also show which part goes into which folder. For example which parts will go into stylesheet etc. or maybe css

Comment: @RobinLundgren Ah man!!! The CSS part to your `style.css` or whatever CSS file you have. And the HTML part with the same HTML part that you have. Just replace it.

Comment: @RobinLundgren Check out the updated answer to see it in white colour.